# Basic MySQL Commands Meaning

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm new to SQL and I'm confused on this 'delete duplicate' question.

A table named 'Person' contains two columns: Id and Email, and I want to delete all duplicate email entries in this table, keeping only unique emails based on its smallest Id.

The answer should be like:

```
DELETE p1 
FROM Person p1, Person p2
WHERE p1.Email = p2.Email 
AND p1.Id > p2.Id
```

My question is that what is p1 here? What does the usage ‘Person p1’ mean？

Comment: hi, `Person p1` is a [table alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)).

Comment: Should I state "Person AS p1" first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a table, which is called `person_office_job_join` which is quite a mouthful. The `p1` and `p2` are aliases. that means that you can simplify references to your table.

e.g.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM person LEFT JOIN person_office_job_join poj 
WHERE poj.person_id =  person.id
```

is the same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM person LEFT JOIN person_office_job_join  
WHERE person_office_job_join.person_id =  person.id
```

In your specific case, it allows you to join on the same table, thereby finding the duplicates. Imagine a more complex query, where you want to do more stuff, while specifying the table name. having a shorthand reference is great.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems like "person_office_job_join poj " is short for "person_office_job_join AS poj "